# Download the generated table in a csv format - R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

My shiny app generates a table that I want to make available for download in a csv format.

```
  ui = fluidPage( ...
         tableOutput("contents"),
         downloadButton("download", "Download results in csv format") 
)
```

```
server <- function( input, output, session ) {
   
   output$contents <- renderTable( ... )
  

output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(contents, ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(contents(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
```

I understand that I have to create a reactive object, but the `renderTable` itself uses another reactive object (uploaded dataset), so it looks like I need to nest one reactive object into another, and it does not seem to work. Will appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Added an example using `renderTable` instead of `renderDataTable`, as requested by the question and in the comment section:

Here is an example using the iris dataset. I also added a table from the DT package. You should not paste the data  in the `filename` function, only in the in the `write.csv` function.

````
```{r}
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

```
setosa <- filter(iris, Species == "setosa")

ui = fluidPage(
  downloadButton("download", "Download results in csv format") ,
  column(12,
         DT::dataTableOutput ("content"),
         style = "  overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: scroll;")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$content <-
    renderDataTable(head(setosa))
  output$download <-
    downloadHandler(
      filename = function () {
        paste("MyData.csv", sep = "")
      },
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(content, file)
      }
    )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```
````

**Using** `renderTable` **instead of** `renderDataTable`

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)


setosa <- filter(iris, Species == "setosa")

ui = fluidPage(
  downloadButton("download", "Download results in csv format"),
   tableOutput("table")

  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- data.frame(setosa)
  output$table <-
    renderTable(data)
  output$download <-
    downloadHandler(
      filename = function () {
        paste("MyData.csv", sep = "")
      },
      
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(data, file)
      }
    )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I don't have enough credits to upvote your answer. Anyway, the problem is that my output object is `tableOutput`, changing it to `dataTableOutput` messed some of other functionalities. Is there a way to apply your answer to `tableOutput` and `renderTable`? Thank you

Comment: Yes, it is possible! I added it to my answer. Hope it works!

Comment: I just edited the answer again to add the tableOutput to ui.

Comment: Thank you again! Unfortunately, when I run your second code (verbatim) with the  `renderTable` it gives an error: "Warning: Error in is.data.frame: object 'content' not found [No stack trace available]".

Comment: I think I've solved it: When you add:
 `data <- reactive(data.frame(setosa))
  output$table <- renderTable(data())` and then in the `write.csv`:
`write.csv(data(), file)` it writes the csv file :)

Comment: Your approach doesn't work for me...You don't have to use a reactive expression. [Here is an explanation of reactive expressions](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson6/). I will edit my answer again to try something between your answer and mine. Can you try again?